# Java HttpURLConnection: Content Length computation

Tags: java, http, rest, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I'm currently developing a library for the bitbucket issues RESTful API. I made good progress and now I'm going to tackle the section [Updating an Issue](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BBDEV/Issues#Issues-Updatinganissue) which demands an HTTP PUT Request.

Now I'm stuck because of the HTTP Error Code `411 Length Required`. After a bit of googling, I found the following [code example](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/remember-kids-an-http-content-length-is-the-number-of-bytes-not-the-number-of-characters.html):

```
// CORRECT: get a UTF-8 encoded byte array from the response
// String and set the content-length to the length of the
// resulting byte array.
String response = [insert XML with UTF-8 characters here];
byte[] responseBytes;
try {
    responseBytes = response.getBytes("UTF-8");
}
catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) {
    System.err.print("My computer hates UTF-8");
}

this.contentLength_ = responseBytes.length;
```

Now my question: What is exactly measured?

- the query string
- the urlencoded query string
- only the values of the parameters...??

And is `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(<mycomputedInt>));` an appriopate way of setting the content length attribute?

Examples appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

edit:

For instance, you could explain computation with the following curl example from the bitbucket wiki entry:

```
curl -X PUT -d "content=Updated%20Content" \
https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/sarahmaddox/sarahmaddox/issues/1/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your are doing the request, right. The content-length is the number of bytes of your request body. In your case

```
int content-length = "content=Updated%20Content".getBytes("UTF-8").length;
```

What is exactly measured?

the url encoded query string (when in the request/entity body)

Comment: Please don't use the `getBytes` method without specifying the charset.

Comment: I'm still a lil stuck, but I think this rather depends on the bitbucket api than on how I do requests.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP spec on [411](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.12):

> The server refuses to accept the
>   request without a defined Content-
>   Length. The client MAY repeat the
>   request if it adds a valid
>   Content-Length header field containing
>   the length of the message-body in the
>   request message.

HTTP spec on the [Content-Length header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13):

> The Content-Length entity-header field
>   indicates the size of the entity-body,
>   in decimal number of OCTETs

HTTP spec on [HTTP entity length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html):

```
entity-body := Content-Encoding( Content-Type( data ) )
```

> The entity-length of a message is the
>   length of the message-body before any
>   transfer-codings have been applied.

---

To summarise if you want to send an un-compressed UTF-8 string you would determine the bytes to send as:

```
Identity( UTF-8( "content=Updated%20Content" ) )
```

The Content-Length is set to the number of bytes output.

If you are sending UTF-8 data I would also strongly suggest you set a [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header.